# Numerically solve system of equations with nested variables

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to solve the following system of equations. The first two equations depend on the variable TeV

```
RxA[TeV_] :=   Exp[E1/TeV]/ngas*(2*Pi*(me*mp/mp)*qe*TeV/hp^2)^(3/2);(*kT in eV*)
RxB[TeV_] :=  Exp[E2/TeV]/ngas*(2*Pi*(mp^2/(2*mp))*qe*TeV/hp^2)^(3/2);(*kT in eV*)
eqpart = NSolve[{2*y^2/(x - y) == RxA,4*(x - y)^2/(1 - x) == RxB}, {x, y}];
Plot[Evaluate[{x, y} /. eqpart], {TeV, 0.1, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

I don't understand why there is no output on the plot. Is the syntax ok?

Thanks in advance!
bye!

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

You need to provide values for all of the parameters. I have arbitrarily set them all to `1`

```
me = mp = qe = hp = E1 = E2 = ngas = 1;

RxA[TeV_] := Exp[E1/TeV]/ngas*(2*Pi*(me*mp/mp)*qe*TeV/hp^2)^(3/2);(*kT in eV*)
RxB[TeV_] := 
 Exp[E2/TeV]/ngas*(2*Pi*(mp^2/(2*mp))*qe*TeV/hp^2)^(3/2);(*kT in eV*)
```

You must include arguments for `RxA` and `RxB` in the equations, and since `eqpart` uses a numeric technique it should only be called when `TeV` has a numeric value.

```
eqpart[TeV_?NumericQ] := 
  NSolve[{2*y^2/(x - y) == RxA[TeV], 4*(x - y)^2/(1 - x) == RxB[TeV]}, {x, y}];

Show[
 Plot[#[[1]] /. eqpart[TeV], {TeV, 0.1, 10},
    PlotPoints -> 50,
    PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][#[[2]]]] & /@
  {{x, 1}, {y, 2}},
 Frame -> True,
 Axes -> False,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"TeV", "x, y"}),
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Or, if you want a [`ParametricPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html)

```
ParametricPlot[{x, y} /. eqpart[TeV],
 {TeV, 0.1, 10}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** To use [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) rather than [`NSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html) (and again setting all parameters to `1`)

```
eqns = {2*y^2/(x - y) == RxA[TeV],
  4*(x - y)^2/(1 - x) == RxB[TeV]}

(* {(2 y^2)/(x - y) == 2 Sqrt[2] E^(1/TeV) π^(3/2) TeV^(3/2), (4 (x - y)^2)/(
  1 - x) == E^(1/TeV) π^(3/2) TeV^(3/2)} *)
```

By assuming that `x != y && x != 1` the equations can be put in a more manageable form.

```
eqns2 = eqns // Simplify[#, x != y && x != 1] &

(* {Sqrt[2] E^(1/TeV) π^(3/2) TeV^(3/2) (x - y) == y^2, 
 E^(1/TeV) π^(3/2) TeV^(3/2) (-1 + x) + 4 (x - y)^2 == 0} *)
```

The solutions are each a [`ConditionalExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html) with the condition that `TeV > 0`. Simplifying with this assumption eliminates the condition. The solutions are expressed as [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects.

```
sol = Solve[eqns2, {x, y}, Reals] //
  Simplify[#, TeV > 0] &

(* {{x -> Root[
    E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 - 
      64 E^(6/TeV) π^9 TeV^9 + (-4 E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 - 
         32 Sqrt[2] E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 + 
         128 E^(6/TeV) π^9 TeV^9) #1 + (390 E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 + 
         96 Sqrt[2] E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 - 
         64 E^(6/TeV) π^9 TeV^9) #1^2 + (-772 E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 - 
         96 Sqrt[2] E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6) #1^3 + (-32 E^(
          2/TeV) π^3 TeV^3 + 385 E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 + 
         32 Sqrt[2] E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6) #1^4 + (64 E^(
          2/TeV) π^3 TeV^3 - 
         512 Sqrt[2] E^(2/TeV) π^3 TeV^3) #1^5 + (-32 E^(
          2/TeV) π^3 TeV^3 + 512 Sqrt[2] E^(2/TeV) π^3 TeV^3) #1^6 + 
      256 #1^8 &, 1], 
  y -> Root[-2 E^(
       2/TeV) π^3 TeV^3 Root[
        E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 - 
          64 E^(6/TeV) π^9 TeV^9 + (-4 E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 - 
             32 Sqrt[2] E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 + 
             128 E^(6/TeV) π^9 TeV^9) #1 + (390 E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 + 
             96 Sqrt[2] E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 - 
             64 E^(6/TeV) π^9 TeV^9) #1^2 + (-772 E^(
              4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 - 
             96 Sqrt[2] E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6) #1^3 + (-32 E^(
              2/TeV) π^3 TeV^3 + 385 E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 + 
             32 Sqrt[2] E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6) #1^4 + (64 E^(
              2/TeV) π^3 TeV^3 - 
             512 Sqrt[2] E^(2/TeV) π^3 TeV^3) #1^5 + (-32 E^(
              2/TeV) π^3 TeV^3 + 
             512 Sqrt[2] E^(2/TeV) π^3 TeV^3) #1^6 + 256 #1^8 &, 1]^2 + 
      4 E^(2/TeV) π^3 TeV^3 Root[
        E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 - 
          64 E^(6/TeV) π^9 TeV^9 + (-4 E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 - 
             32 Sqrt[2] E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 + 
             128 E^(6/TeV) π^9 TeV^9) #1 + (390 E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 + 
             96 Sqrt[2] E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 - 
             64 E^(6/TeV) π^9 TeV^9) #1^2 + (-772 E^(
              4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 - 
             96 Sqrt[2] E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6) #1^3 + (-32 E^(
              2/TeV) π^3 TeV^3 + 385 E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 + 
             32 Sqrt[2] E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6) #1^4 + (64 E^(
              2/TeV) π^3 TeV^3 - 
             512 Sqrt[2] E^(2/TeV) π^3 TeV^3) #1^5 + (-32 E^(
              2/TeV) π^3 TeV^3 + 
             512 Sqrt[2] E^(2/TeV) π^3 TeV^3) #1^6 + 256 #1^8 &, 1] #1 - 
      2 E^(2/TeV) π^3 TeV^3 #1^2 + #1^4 &, 2]}, {x -> 
   Root[E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 - 
      64 E^(6/TeV) π^9 TeV^9 + (-4 E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 - 
         32 Sqrt[2] E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 + 
         128 E^(6/TeV) π^9 TeV^9) #1 + (390 E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 + 
         96 Sqrt[2] E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 - 
         64 E^(6/TeV) π^9 TeV^9) #1^2 + (-772 E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 - 
         96 Sqrt[2] E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6) #1^3 + (-32 E^(
          2/TeV) π^3 TeV^3 + 385 E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 + 
         32 Sqrt[2] E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6) #1^4 + (64 E^(
          2/TeV) π^3 TeV^3 - 
         512 Sqrt[2] E^(2/TeV) π^3 TeV^3) #1^5 + (-32 E^(
          2/TeV) π^3 TeV^3 + 512 Sqrt[2] E^(2/TeV) π^3 TeV^3) #1^6 + 
      256 #1^8 &, 2], 
  y -> Root[-2 E^(
       2/TeV) π^3 TeV^3 Root[
        E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 - 
          64 E^(6/TeV) π^9 TeV^9 + (-4 E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 - 
             32 Sqrt[2] E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 + 
             128 E^(6/TeV) π^9 TeV^9) #1 + (390 E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 + 
             96 Sqrt[2] E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 - 
             64 E^(6/TeV) π^9 TeV^9) #1^2 + (-772 E^(
              4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 - 
             96 Sqrt[2] E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6) #1^3 + (-32 E^(
              2/TeV) π^3 TeV^3 + 385 E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 + 
             32 Sqrt[2] E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6) #1^4 + (64 E^(
              2/TeV) π^3 TeV^3 - 
             512 Sqrt[2] E^(2/TeV) π^3 TeV^3) #1^5 + (-32 E^(
              2/TeV) π^3 TeV^3 + 
             512 Sqrt[2] E^(2/TeV) π^3 TeV^3) #1^6 + 256 #1^8 &, 2]^2 + 
      4 E^(2/TeV) π^3 TeV^3 Root[
        E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 - 
          64 E^(6/TeV) π^9 TeV^9 + (-4 E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 - 
             32 Sqrt[2] E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 + 
             128 E^(6/TeV) π^9 TeV^9) #1 + (390 E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 + 
             96 Sqrt[2] E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 - 
             64 E^(6/TeV) π^9 TeV^9) #1^2 + (-772 E^(
              4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 - 
             96 Sqrt[2] E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6) #1^3 + (-32 E^(
              2/TeV) π^3 TeV^3 + 385 E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6 + 

             32 Sqrt[2] E^(4/TeV) π^6 TeV^6) #1^4 + (64 E^(
              2/TeV) π^3 TeV^3 - 
             512 Sqrt[2] E^(2/TeV) π^3 TeV^3) #1^5 + (-32 E^(
              2/TeV) π^3 TeV^3 + 
             512 Sqrt[2] E^(2/TeV) π^3 TeV^3) #1^6 + 256 #1^8 &, 2] #1 - 
      2 E^(2/TeV) π^3 TeV^3 #1^2 + #1^4 &, 2]}} *)
```

The Plots for the two solution sets are

```
Column[
 Plot[Evaluate[{x, y} /. sol[[#[[1]]]]], {TeV, 0.1, 10},
    PlotRange -> #[[2]],
    Frame -> True,
    FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"TeV", ""}),
    ImageSize -> 360,
    PlotLegends -> Placed[{x, y}, {.5, .25}]] & /@
  {{1, Automatic}, {2, All}}]
```

[image]

Your actual parameter values and the context of your problem would presumably tell you which solution set(s) is(are) of interest.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I confirm it works well now. So my problem was mostly linked to the correct syntax to use (as I suspected). If I move from NSolve to Solve, how should I modify your code? Thanks again!